# React Native - undefined is not an object(evaluating '_ref2.label')

Tags: react-native

I am using DropDownPicker in React-Native. I want DropDownPicker to be loaded by default for example first index. I want the 1st item of this.state.allAdresses Array to be loaded as defaultValue. But I am getting the error in the thread. What is the reason?

```
DropDownPicker
 style = {{marginTop:10}} 
             items={this.state.allAdresses.map((item, index)=> ({label:item.firstname + " " + item.lastname + " " + item.address_1 + " " +  item.address_2 + " " + item.city + " " + item.company + " " + item.postcode ,value:item.lastname, key: index}))}
                    placeholder="Adres seçiniz"
                    containerStyle={{height: 40, width:'100%',}}
                    defaultValue={this.state.allAdresses[1]}


                    onChangeItem={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.changeAddress(itemIndex)}

                />
```

Comment: This is because you are referencing ```this.state.allAdresses[1]``` in ```defaultValue``` and that doesn't have a ```label``` property. You need to update the object you are referencing in defaultValue.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are referencing `this.state.allAdresses[1]` in `defaultValue` while defaultValue must be the value of the object you are trying to display as selected.

Here is one way to fix it

```
//Create an array from allAdresses you want to populate dropdownpicker with.

const items = this.state.allAdresses.map((item, index)=> ({label:item.firstname + " " +
item.lastname + " " + item.address_1 + " " + item.address_2 + " " + item.city + " " + item.company + " " +
item.postcode ,value:item.lastname, key: index}))

<DropDownPicker 
  style={{marginTop:10}} 
  //reference it like this
  items={items}
  placeholder="Adres seçiniz"
  containerStyle={{height: 40, width:'100%',}}
  //set 1 index
  defaultValue={items[1].value}
  onChangeItem={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.changeAddress(itemIndex)}
  />
```

Comment: Thank you, I keep getting the same problem again

Comment: Does ```allAdresses``` have data for the [1] index?

Comment: Yes, 1st item is available

Comment: Oh, I know what's the error. Updated my answer. defaultValue should be ```defaultValue={items[1].value}```